# Flask session not persisting after refresh

Tags: python, session, flask

I have this route in a flask app:

```
@APP.route('/comparisons', methods=['POST'])
def save_comparison():
    if 'comparisons' not in session or not session['comparisons']:
        session['comparisons'] = []
    entity_id = request.form.get('entity_id')
    session['comparisons'].append(entity_id)
    session.modified = True
    return entity_id

APP.secret_key = 'speakfriend'
```

This adds `entity_id`s to `session['comparisons']` as expected. However, when I refresh the page, the session object does not have a `'comparisons'` property anymore, so the list of comparisons is empty. What am I missing?

#### Update:

I left out what I didn't know was the important information. The vue app also makes calls to a flask api, which sets its own session. The `SECRET_KEY`s were different. So, when there was an api call between webserver calls (or visa versa) the session from one application would be replaced by the session from the other.  Neither was mutually intelligible (different `SECRET_KEY`s).  Since these are always deployed together using `docker-compose` the solution was to use a common an env variable to pass the same secret to both.

Comment: Are you submitting the form with an ajax post request?

Comment: yes, this is an endpoint for an ajax request.  I know the form data is getting to the route, but it does not persist.

Comment: I ran sample code and it worked just fine for me. session['comparisons'] was extended every time I loaded the page (I sent the ajax post request on each page load). Is the request coming from another domain? Are you using the built in development server or are you serving the site using a third party web server (ie IIS)?

Comment: I'm using the development server. However - this app is one micro-service of many, all served by nginx. Could this be fouling things up?

Comment: In my case, the problem was colliding sessions. The vue app also makes calls to a flask api, which sets its own session. The `SECRET_KEY`s were different. So, when there was an api call between webserver calls (or visa versa) the session could not be decrypted and new (empty) data were returned, as if we'd never been there.

Setting the `secret_key` to be the same secret as the api did the trick.